Guidelines for using downward-facing LEDs
I am reworking an existing PCB layout where most components are mounted on the top side of the board, with the exception of 3- through-hole LEDs mounted on the bottom of the board.  I would like to replace those LEDs with SMD versions - but on the same top layer as the rest of the components.  I have seen boards in the past where the light emitted from the LED comes out from the bottom rather than the top.
Can anyone point me towards design guidance for incorporating those LEDs into my design?

Yes, I've used them in designs, but, other than what's on the LED datasheets, I've not seen much in the way of guidelines for any kind of 'indicator' LEDs (as opposed to the detailed application data from the likes of Luxeon for big LEDs.

What do you need to know? It's really not very complicated. Find a suitable part, that is made for mounting downwards of course, and use the footprint that is shown in the datasheet. As easy as pie.

Yeah I mean, they work; follow the manufacturer footprint (give or take assembly input on the solder joint design, and board fab tolerances), and any guides for how to implement that in your EDA tool of choice (a non-plated hole or slot is required).

Yes, I have used 1206 size SMD LEDs this way.
The pad geometry I used was 1.0 x 1.8 mm, 3.556 mm (140 mil) pad distance center to center. The drill diameter of the hole in the center was 2.3 mm.
So there was 0.1 mm distance left between the hole and the pad.
In the first assembly we used the LED 156120VS75000 from Würth Elektronik, no issues at 3200 LEDs.
Then we tried to use APTR3216ZGCK from Kingbright, in this case the plastic body was 1.4 x 1.6 mm rectangular in size and we used the same hole. One assembly error was found in 3200 LEDs, not really a problem.

Did you have the hole through the PCB plated or non-plated?  I am leaning towards non-PTH but was wondering if the hole plating might increase the light output?

@DwayneReid The hole was not plated. I had the same idea, but there is a risk, that this might shortcut the LED pads if the drill is not perfectly aligned.
